# how to deal with UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp and UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown?

Tags: ios, uiinterfaceorientation, uidevice

a noob question here.

i detect the orientation with:

`UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`

all is fine and dandy and I reposition my text fields and labels according to the reported orientation with

`if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)`

and else{} for everything else

the problem that i only recently discovered is when the `UIDevice` reports `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` or `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown`. how do I deal with this situation ? how do I know whether `UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp` and `UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown` is happening in Portrait or Landscape ? I know that the device is facing up or down, but I don't know if I should reposition everything to Portrait or Landscape.

thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apple recommends against using *device* orientation for view layout. Instead, each view controller has an [interfaceOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW12) property, and `UIApplication` has a [statusBarOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW10) property, both of which will return the current *interface* orientation, which is suitable for view layout.

To monitor for changes, there are `UIViewController` methods like [willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW28) that will be called and notifications such as [UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW45) that will be posted when an interface orientation change occurs.

Comment: This is the correct answer, just refactoring the UIDevice orientation  response (as the blog suggests) isn't as good as listening to the interfaceOrientation of the UIViewController. Nice work.

Comment: I like this answer better as well. caprica13, could you mark this one as correct?

Comment: There are cases where one needs to layout a view based on the device orientation rather than the UI orientation. Look at the native camera app or Instagram's camera screen for example - the containers remain fixed with the UI orientation, while the icons rotate with the device orientation.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, hopefully it would help some one.

For iOS 6.0 and later:

1) Set this code during your View Setup to receive rotation notification:

```
  // Set Listener to receive orientation notifications from the device
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                           selector:@selector(detectOrientation)
                                               name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                             object:nil];
```

2) Set this code to catch the Notification after rotation:

```
-(void)detectOrientation{      
  switch ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]) {
    case UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown:{
      NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown");
      break;
    }
    case UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp:{
      NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp");
      break;
    }
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:{
      NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft");
      break;
    }
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:{
      NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight");
      break;
    }
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:{
      NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationPortrait");
      break;
    }
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:{
      NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown");
      break;
    }
    case UIDeviceOrientationUnknown:{
      NSLog(@"UIDeviceOrientationUnknown");
      break;
    }
    default:{
      break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problems with

> [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

This method generate notifications for 7 possible device positional states:

```
UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp
UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
UIDeviceOrientationUnknown
```

But I only need the first 4, well this is my approach to solve this problem (with code included):
[How to handle UIDeviceOrientation for manage views layouts](http://www.littleaps.com/littleAps_Software/littleBlog/Entradas/2011/6/16_How_to_handle_UIDeviceOrientation_for_manage_views_layouts.html)